# Make a TabPage flash on event

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, tabcontrol

I'm in the stages of making a program which will require a tabpage to flash when an event happens

I've googled around, and i came across this: [Blink tab header on receiving event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689057/blink-tab-header-on-receiving-event). This is similar, but uses WPF, and i'm using WinForms, and i'm not even sure that does what i want :L

I've also found this: [C#: Flash Window in Taskbar via Win32 FlashWindowEx](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/26/CSharp-Flash-Window-in-Taskbar-via-Win32-FlashWindowEx.aspx). This is what i want, but obvious for the whole form, and in the taskbar, not 'in form'

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not saying this is the best way or even a great way to accomplish this, but it does work. I've used code similar to this when I needed to something similar.

The tabControl1 has two tabs and I blink tab 1 (the second tab).

For my example that I threw together, I set tabControl1's `DrawMode` property to "OwnerDrawFixed" and then a couple of buttons which start/stop the timer.  The interval was something like 750ms but you could choose whatever, of course.  On a `timer1_Tick` event, I swap out the current color and tell the `tabControl1` to refresh itself.  That'll make the `DrawItem` event get raised and then I either draw the rectangle the current color if it is tab page 1 or the backcolor if not.  Then I draw the tabpage's text.

It works.  Could use some tweaking for sure.  Give it a whirl!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Color currentColor = Color.Green;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentColor == Color.Yellow)
            currentColor = Color.Green;
        else
            currentColor = Color.Yellow;
        tabControl1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

    }

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled && e.Index == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(currentColor), e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), e.Bounds);
        }
        Rectangle paddedBounds = e.Bounds;
        paddedBounds.Inflate(-2, -2);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, this.Font, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, paddedBounds);
    }
}
```